# Batch File - Adding Whitespace when Writing to File

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have an issue when I write data to a batch file.

```
Input Data:
4


Code:

CLS
@ECHO OFF


set VBoxEXE="C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" 
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\someuser\readthis.txt) DO SET read=%%x
SET /a display=%read%+1
set VMPath="C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox\VirtualMachines\Lubuntu(32-Bit)_Clone_%read%.vdi"
set VMClone="C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox\VirtualMachines\Lubuntu(32-Bit)_Clone_%display%.vdi"
ECHO Creating a new Virtual Machine
ECHO %VMPATH%
ECHO %display%
ECHO Old Version: %read%
ECHO New Version: %display%
REM %VBoxEXE% clonevdi %VMPath% %VMClone%
ECHO %display% > "C:\Users\someuser\readthis.txt"
```

I'm reading a number from a text file, in my case 4 is printed in the batch file. When I read it in, I add 1 to it, and then use it when I'm cloning my virtual machine. It works, BUT, when I print the updated version, in my case after adding, it would print 5 to the text file. The issue I'm having is that it prints 5 and then whitespace afterward so that my VMtoClone becomes:

"C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox\VirtualMachines\Lubuntu(32-Bit)_Clone_5 .vdi" The white space after the 5 throws off command prompt and it can't find my file. How do I properly write data to a text file so that it doesn't add whitespace, so I can read from it later?

Comment: Use `ECHO(%display%> "C:\Users\someuser\readthis.txt"`, note `ECHO(` and **no space** before `>` redirector!

Comment: This worked for me: (ECHO %display%) > "C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox\VirtualMachines\log.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not in the incremented value as the `set /a` will remove the ending spaces from the value. Your problem is in `%read%` variable that will retrieve the spaces as they are not discarded.

Remove `"tokens=* delims="` in your `for /f` command to remove aditional spaces.

To avoid the inclusion of spaces by the script, change the `echo` line to any of the following lines

```
(ECHO %display%) > "C:\Users\someuser\readthis.txt"
```

or

```
> "C:\Users\someuser\readthis.txt" ECHO %display%
```